# how to scroll horizontally in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to scroll horizontally In ionic+ angular .Actually I want to display data in grid view and four item in each slide .
I want to use in slide as shown in this url 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/
if there is more item in array example I take six 6 object .I need to ass slide and insert two item in another slide

In other words I need to display 4 or four item in each slide if there is more item in array I need to add slide which scroll horizontally here is my code

http://play.ionic.io/app/4a3adb5bb8f1

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('firstContrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.data = [{
        name: " This is a basic jjj   text."

    }, {
        name: " This is a basic Card1  text."

    }, {
        name: " This is a basic Card2  text."

    }, {
        name: " This is a basic Card3  text."

    },
    {
        name: " This is a basic Card4  text."

    },
    {
        name: " This is a basic Card5  text."

    }]

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <ion-scroll direction="x" class="wide-as-needed">

     Your content

    </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: actually it is dynamic .. mean may be there is 2 element and may be 2000 elemet

Comment: could you you share plunker

Answer (score 0):

Angular have a sidebar component.

```
npm install --save ng-sidebar
```

then Add SidebarModule to your app module:

```
import { SidebarModule } from 'ng-sidebar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, SidebarModule.forRoot()],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
class AppModule {}
```

and then

Your page content should be in some container with a ng-sidebar-content attribute.

```
<ng-sidebar-container>

      <!-- container-->

</ng-sidebar-container>
```